# Unable to Install Android Emulator for AMD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, amd-processor

I have Windows 10 Pro and AMD Ryzen 5 processor. I am following the official tutorial to enable android emulator for AMD found here:

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/emulator-29211-and-amd-hypervisor-12-to.html

My problem lies when trying to install the emulator from the SDK tools screen on Android Studios.

[image: SKD Tools Screen]

I get this error:

```
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:
The service has not been started.

[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
```

I have checked for solutions here, Github and Youtube but none of the solutions resolve my problem.

Steps I have taken:

- Enabled SWM Mode in the BIOS
- Checked that Hyper-V, Windows Hypervison Platform, Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Sandbox are deactivated:

  [image: image description]
- Ran the Silent_Install.Bat file directly from the file explorer using Administrator Command Line. I.e. I did not get the screen shown here:

  [image: image description]
- Disabled Virtualization Based Security in Device Guard
- Ran "Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V" in Admin PowerShell Window
- Reinstalled Android Studio and all associated files
- Deactivated my VPN to see if that made a difference (grasping at straws at this point!)

I have seen suggestions that my antivirus may be the culprit. I use AVG Free and have looked for a 'Disable Virtualization' option but there does not seem to be one.

Also would the fact that the folder where the `Silent_Install.bat` is located insists to be called `Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2` despite there not being a `Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver` folder have any effect?

Any feedback or advice that anyone can give me would be much appreciated. I spent far too long trying to fix this already and I just want to start with the Android Studio Beginners course.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally found the answer!

I was right it is to do with my antivirus. For AVG you need to go to Settings and search for "Virtualization". Then you need to disable "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization".

Restart and it should work!